# Javascript check multiple dropdowns, conditional return false not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple dropdowns created, and am checking to see if any of the class dropdown is selected. Then, it should alert and it is doing that, but the problem  is the other function in the if condition as also triggering though there is a return false condition

The if condition should only trigger if the all the class dropdown are selected

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shaikasifpasha3/d9z72do7/)

```js
function addcourse() {

  // The .each() method is unnecessary here:
  $(".DD_Sub").each(function() {

    if ($("option:selected", this).val() == "  Select Subject  "); {

      alert("");
      return false;
    }
    
  });

  if ($("#BodyHolder_DDClass option:selected").text() == "  Select Class  ") {

    alert("Select class");

  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DD_Sub1" class="DD_Sub" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
  <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
  <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
  <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
  <option value="ECO-20">ECO-20</option>
  <option value="ECO-21">ECO-21</option>
  <option value="ECO-22">ECO-22</option>
  <option value="ENG-20">ENG-20</option>

</select>
<select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DD_Sub1" class="DD_Sub" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
  <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
  <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
  <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
  <option value="ECO-20">ECO-20</option>
  <option value="ECO-21">ECO-21</option>
  <option value="ECO-22">ECO-22</option>
  <option value="ENG-20">ENG-20</option>
</select>
<select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DD_Sub1" class="DD_Sub" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
  <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
  <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
  <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
  <option value="ECO-20">ECO-20</option>
  <option value="ECO-21">ECO-21</option>
  <option value="ECO-22">ECO-22</option>
  <option value="ENG-20">ENG-20</option>
</select>
<select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DD_Sub1" class="DD_Sub" style="height:27px;width:150px;">
  <option value="Select Subject">Select Subject</option>
  <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
  <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
  <option value="ECO-20">ECO-20</option>
</select>

<select name="ctl00$BodyHolder$DDClass" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$BodyHolder$DDClass\',\'\')', 0)" id="BodyHolder_DDClass" style="height:27px;width:150px;float:left;">
  <option value="Select Class">Select Class</option>
  <option value="I BA HEG">I BA HEG</option>
  <option value="I BA HEK">I BA HEK</option>
  <option value="I BA HEP">I BA HEP</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" name="ctl00$BodyHolder$Add_New_period_button" value="Add Period" onclick="return addcourse();" id="BodyHolder_Add_New_period_button">
```

Comment: Have you tried using JQuery's `.hasClass()`? https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if($("option:selected").hasClass( "Select" )){
    alert("Not valid");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Am not sure u understand ed my problem say i have four drop down with the class`''DD_Sub''`and one with the id `BodyHolder_DDClass` and what am trying to say is if any of the dropdown with the class `DD_Sub` has a selected text `Select Subject` then that should alert it is alerting but the problm is it should not proceed further in my case the id dd `BodyHolder_DDClass` aert also shows up

Comment: So you wanna reach all the `option` tags?

Comment: yes correct can u join me hear if u dont mind http://jsfiddle.net/shaikasifpasha3/d9z72do7/2/#&togetherjs=tc2vMJUa0v